# Wildfly hibernate could not create database connection

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc, wildfly-10

I am the new to the whole widlfly-hibernate, at work we use tomcat-mybatis

I am trying to connect Wildfly 10.0 using Hibernate 5.1.0 with MySQL

How i connect:

```
try {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

            configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/foxtrot");
            configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "root");
            configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", "");
            configuration.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
            configuration.setProperty("hibernate.current_session_context_class", "thread");
            configuration.setProperty("hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings", "false");
            configuration.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");

            configuration.addAnnotatedClass(AccountEntity.class);

            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                    .applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
            return configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            System.out.println(ex.getStackTrace());
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
```

I receive the following error: `org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect`

Sql exception: `java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.`

I am using wamp and i have preinstall phpmyadmin and i can connect without a problem

```
11:23:06,457 INFO  [stdout] (default task-5) Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
11:23:06,457 INFO  [stdout] (default task-5) org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:244)
11:23:06,458 INFO  [stdout] (default task-5) org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:208)
11:23:06,458 INFO  [stdout] (default task-5) org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
11:23:06,458 INFO  [stdout] (default task-5) org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
11:23:06,458 INFO  [stdout] (default task-5) org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
11:23:06,459 INFO  [stdout] (default task-5) org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217)
11:23:06,459 INFO  [stdout] (default task-5) org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
11:23:06,463 INFO  [stdout] (default task-5) org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
11:23:06,464 INFO  [stdout] (default task-5) org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
11:23:06,464 INFO  [stdout] (default task-5) org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
11:23:06,465 INFO  [stdout] (default task-5) org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
11:23:06,465 INFO  [stdout] (default task-5) org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
11:23:06,465 INFO  [stdout] (default task-5) org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:692)
11:23:06,465 INFO  [stdout] (default task-5) utility.HibernateUtils.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtils.java:46)
11:23:06,465 INFO  [stdout] (default task-5) utility.HibernateUtils.<clinit>(HibernateUtils.java:13)
11:23:06,465 INFO  [stdout] (default task-5) utility.Dao.openCurrentSession(Dao.java:16)
11:23:06,465 INFO  [stdout] (default task-5) services.AccountService.findByKeyAndType(AccountService.java:73)
11:23:06,466 INFO  [stdout] (default task-5) handlers.AuthHandler.Handle(AuthHandler.java:37)
11:23:06,466 INFO  [stdout] (default task-5) Server.OnBinary(Server.java:84)
11:23:06,466 INFO  [stdout] (default task-5) sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
11:23:06,466 INFO  [stdout] (default task-5) sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
11:23:06,466 INFO  [stdout] (default task-5) sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
11:23:06,466 INFO  [stdout] (default task-5) java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
11:23:06,466 INFO  [stdout] (default task-5) io.undertow.websockets.jsr.annotated.BoundMethod.invoke(BoundMethod.java:87)
11:23:06,466 INFO  [stdout] (default task-5) io.undertow.websockets.jsr.annotated.AnnotatedEndpoint$2$1.run(AnnotatedEndpoint.java:150)
11:23:06,467 INFO  [stdout] (default task-5) io.undertow.websockets.jsr.ServerWebSocketContainer.invokeEndpointMethod(ServerWebSocketContainer.java:553)
11:23:06,467 INFO  [stdout] (default task-5) io.undertow.websockets.jsr.annotated.AnnotatedEndpoint$2.onMessage(AnnotatedEndpoint.java:145)
11:23:06,467 INFO  [stdout] (default task-5) io.undertow.websockets.jsr.FrameHandler$6.run(FrameHandler.java:245)
11:23:06,467 INFO  [stdout] (default task-5) io.undertow.websockets.jsr.ServerWebSocketContainer.invokeEndpointMethod(ServerWebSocketContainer.java:553)
11:23:06,467 INFO  [stdout] (default task-5) io.undertow.websockets.jsr.ServerWebSocketContainer$5.run(ServerWebSocketContainer.java:538)
11:23:06,467 INFO  [stdout] (default task-5) io.undertow.websockets.jsr.OrderedExecutor$ExecutorTask.run(OrderedExecutor.java:67)
11:23:06,467 INFO  [stdout] (default task-5) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
11:23:06,468 INFO  [stdout] (default task-5) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
11:23:06,468 INFO  [stdout] (default task-5) java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
11:23:06,469 INFO  [stdout] (default task-5) Error java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

Comment: can you post your full stack trace of exception?

Comment: Yes, ofcourse. Updated*

Comment: I think you forgot to set `password` while setting the properties

Comment: My password is simply empty. I am running on a localhost under a firewall and nobody can't connect besides me. Thats why it is empty - ""

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22647598/amazon-aws-ubuntu-java-mysql-webservice-error-calling-driverconnect

Comment: have you added `com.mysql.jdbc_5.1.5.jar` this jar to you build path?

Comment: @subburoyal MySQL Connector/J 5.1.5 is ancient (at least 8 years old).

Comment: mysql-connector-java version 6.0.2, this is latest version i found on maven repository @PeterMmm i read this answer and it does not provide any help for me, as i said i can successfully connect through phpmyadmin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem came from mysql connector driver i used to use 6.0.2 on 5+ mysql server, now i am using driver 5.+ and everything is working properly